# Rails 4 - Invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 when generating a spreadsheet

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, axlsx

In my rails app, I'm trying to attach a generated xlsx file (basic) in a Sidekiq delayed mail. I'm getting the error: `WARN: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8` every time I run the sending jobs. I'm using the `[axlsx_rails]` gem, and here's my code:

mailer.rb

```
xlsx = (render_to_string handlers: [:axlsx], formats: [:xlsx],
    template: "report", layout: false)
attachments["#{subject}.xlsx"] = { mime_type: Mime::XLSX, content: xlsx }
```

report.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb.add_worksheet(:name => "Custom Report") do |sheet|
   sheet.add_row ["wrap", "me", "Up in Red"], :style => red_border
   sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3], :style => blue_border
end
```

Gem version 0.3.0, Rails 4.1.7, Ruby 2.2.0

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Some people have had that error and I've never been able to reproduce it or track it down. Does it work without the delayed job? If so, then I would search for UTF8 errors with Sidekiq. If not, then there may be rails encoding issues. If none of that works, create an issue on Github and share your Gemfile, and perhaps more of your code/configuration. https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/issues/new

Comment: @noel issue: https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails/issues/37